# Functions to make 'pasted' windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Using tkinter I want to implement a funny feature in my programm. Clicking on the button which represents date of the month in my [calendar.window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNegV.jpg) showing up a [new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilJZ9.jpg) where anyone can make notes and this window must be "pasted" to calendar.window. Trying to pull whether the first or the last window must result in dragging [both of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi35a.jpg). [Example of the wrong dragging.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipJ5h.jpg)  If there is no that function maybe there are means to make windows to appear in pre-defined position and disable dragging function.

Main_module

```
import tkinter as tk
import re
from Calendar import show_calendar
from Notes_widget import show_notes_widget

class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.init_main()

        # Configuring Frame object on the Main window
    def init_main(self):
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(text='Choose the date', width=20, height=3, command=show_calendar)
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(text='Enter your notes', width=20, height=3,
                              command=lambda : show_notes_widget(self.get_root_position()))

        self.btn1.pack()
        self.btn2.pack()

    def get_root_position(self):
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.width, self.height, self.x, self.y = re.split(r'[x+]', root.geometry())
        return self.width, self.height, self.x, self.y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Creating Main window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('ИВРО')
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.width = 180
    root.height = 110
    root.x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
    root.y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
    root.geometry(f'{root.width}x{root.height}+{int(root.x - root.width / 2)}+{int(root.y - root.height / 2)}')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    # Creating Frame object
    app = MainMenu(root)
    app.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

and the second module

```
import tkinter as tk

class NotesWidget(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        self.width, self.height, self.x, self.y = args
        self.init_child()

    def init_child(self):
        self.title("Введите заметку")

        self.text = tk.Text(self, height = 26, width = 35, bg="darkgreen", fg='white',
                            wrap='word', font=('Verdana', 10, 'bold'))
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.grid_propagate(True)
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text='Добавить')
        self.btn.pack(ipady=10)


        self.geometry(f'300x465+{int(self.x) + int(self.width) + 12}+{int(self.y) - int(self.height)}')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()


def show_notes_widget(coordinates):
    width, height, x, y = coordinates
    notes_widget=NotesWidget(width, height, x, y)
    notes_widget.mainloop()
```

Comment: The question is unclear, maybe example this with the help of photos or code.

Comment: Having two windows stuck together like that ("docked" is the more usual term) seems like a lot of effort for no actual benefit.  Why not have the day's notes in a text field in the same window as the calendar?

Comment: Cause text window is used by another module and I plan to enlarge its functionality sooner or later. Is it possible to stuck a window to precise place anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're asking for is more commonly referred to as "docked" rather than "pasted"

While tkinter doesn't directly support that, it's pretty easy to simulate. Tkinter provides methods for moving a window, and a way to know when a window is moved. All you need to do is detect when the main window moves, and move the other window to match the new location.

The event `<Configure>` will be triggered whenever a window is moved (and for a few other reasons). Adding a binding to that event works well to keep the docked window in the right location.

Here's a simple example. The second will lag behind when the main window is moved, but I think that's unavoidable.

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

root = tk.Tk()
other = tk.Toplevel(root)

def dock(child, master):
    width, height, x, y = re.split(r'[x+]', master.geometry())
    x = int(x) + master.winfo_width()
    child.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")

root.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: dock(other, root))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bryan Oakley, now I'm stuck with adding dock() function into my code. There are two modules and I fully don't understand how to bind them together