# How to put a window and a toplevel side by side in Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, widget, toplevel

```
from tkinter import *

def graphical_grid_init():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("2048")
    w = Toplevel(root)
    w.title("2048")
    
    root.mainloop()

graphical_grid_init()
```

This code spawns 2 windows but I want them to be side by side, and apparently i can't call the fonction "grid" after my toplevel window (for example : `w.grid(column=1)`) to place it as it is not a widget, however in our subject they ask us to do so.
How could i place my windows side-by-side ?
Thanks

Comment: Isnt [geometry](http://www.eso.org/projects/vlt/sw-dev/tcl8.4.19/html/TkCmd/wm.htm#M26) what you looking for? You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352918/how-to-center-a-window-on-the-screen-in-tkinter)

Comment: `w.geometry(f'+{px}+{px}')` is what you need to use, keep in mind, you will have to come up with something dynamic, because your pixels wont be same as someone elses.

Comment: The answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64796252/5317403) may be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cool Cloud said,

> w.geometry(f'+{px}+{px}') is what you need to use, keep in mind, you
> will have to come up with something dynamic, because your pixels wont
> be same as someone elses.

So here is a solution

```py
from tkinter import *


def graphical_grid_init():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("2048")
    width,height = 200,100 # with and height of the root window
    w = Toplevel(root)
    w.title("2048")
    w_width,w_height = 200,100 # width and height of the toplevel window

    setwinwidth = ((root.winfo_screenwidth()-width)//2) - width//2
    setwinheight = (root.winfo_screenheight()-height)//2
    settopwidth = ((root.winfo_screenwidth()-w_width)//2) + w_width//2
    settopheight = (root.winfo_screenheight()-w_height)//2

    root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+{setwinwidth}+{setwinheight}")
    w.geometry(f"{w_width}x{w_height}+{settopwidth}+{settopheight}")

    root.mainloop()

graphical_grid_init()
```

here, I get the  actual width and height of the user's screen using the methods, `winfo_screenwidth` and `winfo_screenheight`. Then I use these sizes as well as the sizes provided for the two windows to be displayed, to dynamicaly resize and position the windows on the screen.